# Java illegale conversion from Collection to AbstractCollection

Tags: java, collections, abstract-class

I'm getting the following error:

```
type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<E> to AbstractCollection<E>
```

Google shows no relevant results on the first couple of pages and I'm sure there is a valid reason for Collection to not extend Abstract Collection.

I saw a post here on StackOverflow, but they only got into inheritance without really giving any reasons for this kind of behaviour (what does "Collection" violate in "AbstractCollection"?)

I use AbstractCollection a lot and ran into this when using HashMap's "values" as a result to an AbsractCollection-yielding function.

What should I be using instead of AbstractCollection as a default, non-specific, return type for collections?

Comment: How about using Collection instead?

Comment: Is collection more general than AbstractCollection? If I want to change my implementations, would "Collection" be more flexible? This is counter-intuitive because "Abstract" usually hints "more general"

Comment: yes. It is better to use it as it is more general.

Comment: Potentially even `Iterable` if all you are doing is looping over the `Collection`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E>`.  So, you can just use `Collection<E>`, which is as you want, more general.

This means that you will be able to handle anything that implements `Collection` as opposed to only being able to handle anything that extends `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got it the other way around and missed the direction when inspecting the java documentation!

So to wrap up, collection is the super-type for collections, and not abstractcollection?

Comment: @ReutSharabani `AbstractCollection` implements `Collection`, so `Collection` is the "super-type" if you will.  Hence, it's more general...

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use `Collection` as a type, rather than `AbstractCollection` as it is more general.

If a class implements `Collection` but doesn't extend `AbstractCollection`, it'll work (this is exactly what happened to you here)

Answer (score 1):

AbstractCollection class implements the Collection interface and this class extends the class Object.So first of all my suggestion is use Collection interface instead of using AbstractionCollection. It is more powerful and parent class of AbstractionCollection.